# Excel Formula - Lookup , Index Match Sumifs combination to find the first occurence

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have two tables that look like these:
[image]

Each order ID can appear many times without limit. The total sales amount in col E is the total amount of all sales with that Order ID in OrderDetail Table, so in this case total sales amount for order 122 should be 97.

However, if there is ANY occurrence of "Cancel" in col J, regardless of how many times the order is made, ALL sales amount for that order ID is cancelled. So for this example, the total sales amount for Order 120 and 121 should be zero, and "Cancel" status should be recorded for both Order ID in Col D.

I tried these formulas for D4 and E4, dragging them down to the end of the table. But as you can see, the formulas clearly don't work.

```
D4: =INDEX($J$4:$J$11,MATCH(B4,$G$4:$G$11,0))
E4: =SUMIFS($H$4:$H$11,$G$4:$G$11,B$4,$J$4:$J$11,$J$4:$J$11<>"Cancel")
```

The formula can't be array formula, because both tables will keep expanding as new orders coming in.

Anybody can help me with this problem? Maybe I am missing something out, but I just can't seem to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why aren't you using full column references?

Comment: Because they're not Excel table objects，just tables

Comment: @user71812 you can use full column references with standard tables like the ones you have, it is a common practice. The only thing that would stop you is if you've got something else below or above the table. I would recommend using full column references, or if you can't, then convert to an Excel table object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of issues with your ranges not matching in your formulas which could be solved by using full column references instead of just ranges. (As I'm sure Jeeped was about to suggest in the comments)

`INDEX(MATCH())` is returning only the first match in your formula in `D4`, you will do better with using a conditional `COUNTIFS()` instead:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(J:J,"Cancel",G:G,B4)>0,"Cancel","")
```

There's some typos in your second formula that would be easier rectified if you use full column references, this should do the trick:

```
=SUMIFS(H:H,G:G,B4,J:J,"<>Cancel")
```

Comment: Ah you're right! I didn't think about countif, you're right! Thanks for your help!